# Change Android Manifest file sencha

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Iam using sencha packager to package sencha app how do i modify the android manifest file that gets created as part of the build process...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the android manifest file in sencha 2.1rc1 onwards which requires sencha sdk tools v3. But if you are using 2.0 like me then you are out of luck...

To change permissions in packager.json just add extra attribute "permissions": ["CAMERA", ...]